# MemberSuite Rest API SSO Examples

Tags: php

Can anyone please help me to get the MemberSuite Rest API examples(PHP). I am going to build up the SSO in one of my projects.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the Membersuite SDK with example. Hope this will help you to start with the SSO.

https://github.com/membersuite/sdk-php/blob/master/APISample/APIUsageExamples/CreatingARecord.php

you can ask or find any membersuite relevent questions over there community

https://community.membersuite.com/membersuite